# No protocol binding matches the given address' error

Tags: wcf

I am using Visual Studio 2008. I created a WCF application and when I ran the service for the first time from VS IDE (not hosted on IIS), the service opened in the web browser with the address `localhost:1927/`. Every time I run this service from VS IDE, it runs in the same port, i.e 1927

I wanted to change the port number (for some reason), so I gave specific address `localhost:1928` in the `web.config` file. When I run the web service in IDE after this change, I keep getting the following error.

> No protocol binding matches the given address 'localhost:1928/'. Protocol bindings are configured at the Site level in IIS or WAS configuration.

Following is the `<service>` section from the `web.config` file.

```
<service name="EMS.ServiceImplementation.EmployeeService"
         behaviorConfiguration="EM.EmployeeServiceBehavior" >
   <endpoint name="httpEndPoint" 
       address="http://localhost:1928/" 
       binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""  
       contract="EMS.ServiceContracts.IEmployeeService" />
   <endpoint name="MEXEndPoint" 
       address="mex" 
       binding="mexHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration=""
       contract="IMetadataExchange" />
</service>
```

My specific questions are:

1. How does VS IDE run the service always on the same port which it picked in the first run? Where is this information stored? (I looked through all files in the solution but I couldn't find port 1927 mentioned anywhere).
2. How can I make the service run on a different port?

(Please note that, I have seen similar threads in Stackoverflow, but they relate to service hosted in IIS)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this in the Solution Explorer under the Project Properties. There's a tab called `Web` where you can tell Visual Studio whether to use the default auto-assigned port, or a specific fixed port of your choosing:

[image]

Any non-standard settings will be stored into your `YourProject.csproj` file.

Answer (score 2):

Just leave the address attribute empty and it is solved.